# How to create database field in Marklogic Server?

Tags: xml, field, marklogic

I have the following xml structure

```
 <patent-assignors>
        <patent-assignor>
          <name>VOLPENHEIN, ROBERT A.</name>
          <execution-date>
        <date>19841204</date>
          </execution-date>
        </patent-assignor>
 </patent-assignors>


    <patent-assignees>
        <patent-assignee>
          <name>PROCTER &amp; GAMBLE COMPANY, THE</name>
          <address-2>A CORP. OF  OHIO</address-2>
          <city>CINCINNATI</city>
          <state>OHIO</state>
        </patent-assignee>
   </patent-assignees>
```

I want to create a Database field in Marklogic Server for `patent-assignor` & `patent-assignee`
 so that I can use `cts:field-word-query`.  But I want to search the name of patent-assignor and patent-assignee (both contain the same element "`name`").  Can anyone tell me how can I map field for patent-assignor to patent assignor name and patent-assignee to patent assignee name so that I can use `cts:field-word-query` on names of patent-assignor and patent-assignee. I want an exact match.

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't really sound like a use case for a Field index. Just put an index on element '`name`', and both cases will be indexed in the same index. To make a distinction, wrap a `word-query` or `value-query` with an `element-query` for the appropriate parent element.

Comment: I am not talking about indexes here. I want to create a field not an index !

Comment: @puneet-pant You might be interested in the following section of the MarkLogic Admin Guide, it explains how Fields work, and what options you have: http://docs.marklogic.com/5.0doc/docapp.xqy#display.xqy?fname=http://pubs/5.0doc/xml/admin/fields.xml&query=Fields

Comment: I have already gone through this link but could not understand how to map patent-assignor with patent-assignor name and patent-assignee with patent assignee name.  Could you explain me please how to do this ?

Comment: Your question seems to imply you don't know what a 'field' is in MarkLogic.  Be precise about the search you want to run and the results you expect and perhaps someone can help you more.

Answer (score 1):

I think the comments above about making sure you understand the options available  are all important to consider.  If I understand your question correctly, MarkLogic can probably answer your search using only the "universal index".

Because both the assignor and assignee both use an element named "`name`", querying both for an exact match is acutally quite simple (exact match usually implies a `value-query` not a `word-query`)

```
cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("name"), "VOLPENHEIN, ROBERT A.")
```

However if there are more "`name`" elements in your data other than the assignor and assignee and you need to narrow down hits to only come from these an not other "`name`" fields you could use `element-queries` to restrict the search (to get this to scale well please make sure you have `element-word-positions` and `element-value-positions` settings in your database set to true)

```
cts:or-query((

    cts:element-query( xs:QName("patent-assignor"), 
                       cts:element-value-query(
                           xs:QName("name"), 
                           "VOLPENHEIN, ROBERT A.")),

    cts:element-query( xs:QName("patent-assignee"), 
                       cts:element-value-query(
                           xs:QName("name"), 
                           "VOLPENHEIN, ROBERT A."))
))
```

Fields can be very powerful with regards to isolating specific elements, especially when there are complex "includes" and "excludes" logic to follow.  I think it is very likely you can keep things more flexible by just using the "universal index" to do the filtering at query-time.

Comment: The above query could be shortened if you pass multiple QNames to a single element-query. The function accepts a sequence as first argument. Can be very usefull from time to time..

Comment: @derickson Thanks for the detailed explanation.  I have one more question if I want to compare names of Patent Assignor and Patent Assignee and want to return only those results where names of Patent Assignor and Patent Assignee are not same. Then how should I write the query ?

Comment: you can use cts:not-query to compare your values. So that you will get result where the names are not same